# WPf cannot fully display my controls

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, tabcontrol, scrollviewer

I have relectively complex gui, but it cannot display my the whole controls(in the code, it cannot display "EMAIL", "FORWARD",...) on the bottom. what's wrong with this code? Is it because the "Window", "TabControl" or "ScrollViewer".

Thank you so much in advance!

### the code is as below:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    ShowInTaskbar="False" WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" 
    SizeToContent="Height" Title="Window1">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TabControl Name="tabControl1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TabItem Header="A">
                <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <TabControl>
                                <TabItem Header="A1">
                                    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="10"  />
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Name="spG11" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="A11" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="A12" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="A13" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="A14" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="A15" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="A21" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="A22" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="A23" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="A24" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <ComboBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"  IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="False" IsSelected="True" IsEnabled="False"></ComboBoxItem>
                                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="True"></ComboBoxItem>
                                                </ComboBox>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="A25" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <ComboBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" IsEnabled="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="False" IsSelected="True" IsEnabled="False"></ComboBoxItem>
                                                    <ComboBoxItem Content="True"></ComboBoxItem>
                                                </ComboBox>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
                                            <StackPanel >
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" Text="X1" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="X2" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                                        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" Text="X3" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"  Height="150">
                                                    <StackPanel>
                                                        <Grid >
                                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="105"/>
                                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                    </StackPanel>
                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                            <Button  Margin="2,2,2,2" Content="ADD"  Width="50"/>
                                            <Button  Margin="2,2,2,2" Content="DEL"  Width="50" />
                                        </StackPanel>

                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
                                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Y1" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Name="VaAmplitude" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Y2" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Name="VaPhase" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                                        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Y3" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Name="VbAmplitude" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Y4" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Name="VbPhase" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="150">
                                                    <Grid >
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>

                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <CheckBox Content="SELECT" IsChecked="True"/>
                                            <TextBlock Width="12" />
                                            <CheckBox Content="FORWARD" IsChecked="False"/>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                            <Button Content="LIST" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </Grid>
                                </TabItem>

                            </TabControl>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
            <!--  -->
            <TabItem Header="B">
                <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <TabControl Grid.Row="0">
                                <TabItem Header="B1">
                                    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="10"  />
                                            <RowDefinition/>
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <StackPanel Name="spU11" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="B11" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="B12" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="B13" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="B14" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="B15" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="B16" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="5,5,5,5">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="130"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="150"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="B21" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="B22" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="B23" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="B24" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Text="B25" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                                <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Gray" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                            <StackPanel>
                                                <StackPanel>
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="172"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Q1" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="Q2" IsReadOnly="True" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                                        <TextBox Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Q3" TextAlignment="Center" Background="LightBlue" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </StackPanel>
                                                <ScrollViewer HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Height="150">
                                                    <Grid>
                                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="60"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="172"/>
                                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="170"/>
                                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ScrollViewer>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </Border>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" >
                                            <Button Margin="2,2,2,2" Content="ADD"  Width="60"/>
                                            <Button  Margin="2,2,2,2" Content="DEL"  Width="60" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                                            <CheckBox Content="FORWARD" IsChecked="True" />
                                        </StackPanel>

                                    </Grid>
                                </TabItem>

                            </TabControl>

                            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Text="EMAIL" />
                                    <TextBox Width="80"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Width="30" />
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <TextBlock Text="PAT NO" />
                                    <TextBox Width="80"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="testItemLabelValue" Visibility="Hidden">
            <TextBox Margin="0,1,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
            <StackPanel x:Name="labelling"></StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="50">
            <Button Content="YES" Width="70" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
            <TextBox Margin="0,1,0,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Visibility="Hidden" />
            <Button Content="CANCEAL" Width="70" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to specify the Height of your top grid as this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I'm trying your UI and now it works.

P.S. Although this make your UI to works, I will encourage you to read about [User Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.usercontrol.aspx) and try to reduce the complexity of your whole UI by using them (divide and conquer).

Comment: @user1189507 Glad it works! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted as it works for you.